# In Mongoid, can you atomically destroy an embedded document and update its parent?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, persistence, mongoid, destroy

```
class Cart
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :cart_items

  def calculate_prices
    # Set some fields
  end

  def remove_item(item)
    # what goes here?
    calculate_prices
    save
  end
end

class CartItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :cart
end
```

I would like the `remove_item` to atomically remove the cart item from the cart and set some new prices in one `update` to the carts collection.

Is that possible? Maybe some API to mark an embedded item for destroy and then save the cart?

Comment: Have you found out how to work this out?

Comment: Nope. Maybe add a github issue for it? :(

Comment: I see. Maybe we should. Or might we be tackling it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

That is possible, sir. The secret is in `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
class Cart
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :cart_items

  attr_accessible ...

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_items
  attr_accessible :cart_items_attributes

  set_callback(:update, :before) do |document|
    document.calculate_prices
  end

  protected

  def calculate_prices
    # Set some fields
  end

end

class CartItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :cart

  attr_accessible ...
end
```

In the view:

```
= form_for @cart do |f|
  = f.fields_for :cart_items do |n|
    = render "cart_item", :n => n, :cart_item => n.object
```

With that you can delete items from cart, update quantities and recalculate prices in a one single cart `update`.

Comment: What if I didn't need/want/couldn't-use nested attributes? Looking into the code (https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/relations/builders/nested_attributes/many.rb#L117), I can't see how this is different than just calling #destroy?

Comment: @Ben: It's about referenced documents. Embedded documents are updated atomically with parent. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` here is for convenience in form.